# Filter Multiple Users Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently having issues when attempting to follow multiple Twitter accounts.

I'm able to follow multiple account through hardcoding the filter i.e `stream.filter(follow=["UserId"])` however I want to be able to retrieve multiple user inputs and follow each account. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
userNames = [] 

def trackUser():
    try:
        enteredID = followID.get()
        userName = api.get_user(enteredID)
        userNames.append(userName.id)
        for userName in  userNames:
            stream.filter(follow=[str(userName.id)])
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: The stream listener is only initiated for the first user id entered, if I attempt to start a second stream then the script crashes

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Tweepy package, but can you try doing it without a loop? i.e. `stream.filter(follow=[userNames])`.